# VS2017 Django Web Project build fails without bin folder

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2017, ptvs

I have created a Django Web Project in Visual Studio 2017 and i have tried serving static files from a directory defined in `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`.

settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR,
        'static',
    ),
)
```

Once i had this in settings.py my project didn't build anymore. After quite some time battling with the IDE (i had no errors, it just failed to build and it gave no reason why) i figured out that if i copy the bin folder from a hobby project i made some time ago with PTVS and VS 2015, my project builds fine. And I have absolutely no idea why.

The contents of the bin folder are two files:

**Microsoft.PythonTools.WebRole.dll** and **wfastcgi.py**.

I don't have the PC with VS 2015 anymore so i can't check my IDE settings there and i am pretty sure i didn't make any changes nor have i had trouble with settings.py or serving static files in that project.

Can anyone explain why this could be happening? Why is VS 2017 not creating a bin folder but VS 2015 did. Is there something i am missing?

*Using: VS2017 Professional with Python development installed with VS installer - pretty much default settings*